# Link downloaded file to server

Tags: web-applications

I'm trying to figure out a way to allow a user to download a file from the server and edit it, but when they save, it saves back to the server. I'm looking for a method which doesn't involve things such as flash or silverlight if at all possible.

Comment: It would be useful to know the type of file you're dealing with.

Comment: I'm dealing with a whole bunch of file types. For office files we are feeding them directly into office live 365 online. For basic files that have some sort of discrernable text content (.txt, .xml, etc...) we are parsing them directly into a custom created browser-based editor. And for any other file type that we recognize the extension (photoshop and C# files for example), we want to have this mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that. If the document is downloaded for local edition by a local software, it must be voluntarily uploaded by the user.

If that weren't the case, that would be a security breach, as the browser doesn't have to see (and doesn't see) the local files and isn't notified of changes.

Now, if we don't look for a general and easy solution, but accept some collaboration from the user, what do we have ?

- [webdav](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) is commonly used for shared directories on enterprise wan. This web based protocol allows the sharing of documents and many softwares, among them [OpenOffice](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=8327) and [MsOffice](http://www.webdavsystem.com/server/documentation/ms_office_read_only), are able to work with webdav. This protocol is supported by all recent OS, I think.
- some [Document Management Systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_management_system) (among them [KTDMS](https://www.knowledgetree.com/) which I've used in the past) install native (windows) hooks on your computer enabling you to send back the document from the software you use (mainly MsOffice). Those DMS generally also offer standard webdav access in order to be compatible with any OS

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, once a user downloads a file from your server, you have no control about what he does with it. You have other possibilities:

- Don't make the user download the file, but rather show an editor inside the website. This is often possible without Flash/Silverlight, but the (usually JavaScript-based) editors available are often relatively primitive compared to their desktop counterparts, unless you're dealing only with plain text files.
- Tell the user to upload the file again after he modified it. Less intuitive, but also less hassle for you.

Comment: We are already doing the first point, we are looking for a way to handle file types that we don't have an online editor for.

And we can't do the second do to social issues.

Comment: @Vap0r The only other thing i could think of is to use something like webDAV or FTP for the user. But i don't think that's what you want unless you're dealing with a computer-literate userbase.

Answer (score 0):

You want the saved version to be automatically uploaded to the server? If you let them download it to their desktop and edit it there, you have no control over what happens to it, how they edit it, and whether they will upload it.

If you want something editable by users while remaining on the server, have them edit it through a web app on the server. Like Google Docs and so many similar cloud services.

Whether that's viable at all depends on course on what kind of file it is and what kind of editor you need to edit it. Plain text is relatively easy. Some proprietary format isn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the user to be able textfiles that are on your server, you could use a javascript editor like codemirror.
CodeMirror lets you edit the file in the browser and supports program language syntax-highlighting.

Here is a Demo: 
http://codemirror.net/demo/complete.html

or use TinyMCE if you want to hace a Userfriendly  WYSIWYG editor:
http://www.tinymce.com/

Answer (score 0):

try using google drive. They synchronize local copy to sever. Understanding it may help u